# Is there a way to use buttons whilsts a timer is active - The buttons were disabled, but are enabled when the timer starts

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from time import time

q1 = [
        [sg.Text("Question 1!"), sg.Text("Time:"), sg.Text(" ", size=(20,1), key="t")],
        [sg.Text("This is where question 1 will be?"), sg.Button("Start")],
        [sg.Button("Option 1", key="1",button_color=("#ffffff","#151515"), disabled=True, enable_events=True), sg.Button("Option 2", key="2",button_color=("#00ff00", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Option 3", key="3",button_color=("#00ffff","#151515"), disabled=True), sg.Button("Option 4", key="4",button_color=("#ff00ff", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Next Question"), sg.Button("Skip")]
    ]

window = sg.Window("Question 1",q1)

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None:
        break
    if event == "Start":
        window.FindElement('1').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('2').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('3').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement('4').Update(disabled=False)
        window.FindElement("Start").Update(visible=False)
        window.Refresh()

        seconds = 6

        start = time()
        current = time()
        timeleft = seconds

        while timeleft > 0:
            window.FindElement("t").Update(timeleft)
            window.refresh()
            current = time()
            timeleft = int(seconds - (current - start))
            if timeleft <= 0:
                sg.popup("no time left")
                window.FindElement('1').Update(disabled=True)
                window.FindElement('2').Update(disabled=True)
                window.FindElement('3').Update(disabled=True)
                window.FindElement('4').Update(disabled=True)
                window.FindElement("Start").Update(visible=True)
                window.Refresh()
            else:   
                window.FindElement('1').Update(disabled=False)
                window.FindElement('2').Update(disabled=False)
                window.FindElement('3').Update(disabled=False)
                window.FindElement('4').Update(disabled=False)
                window.FindElement("Start").Update(visible=False)
                window.Refresh()

    if event == "1":
        sg.popup("Test 1")
    elif event == "2":
        sg.popup("Test 2")
    elif event == "3":
        sg.popup("Test 3")
    elif event == "4":
        sg.popup("Test 4")
```

This is the code I have tried to do it with. When start is clicked, a timer starts so the question to be answers, however, I dont want the buttons to be able to be clicked before starting, so is there a way to enable a button to be used after being clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

threading make possible to run different part of code concurrently. by using threading you make option clickable. try this code which allow you click the button when time run.

```
# for making screen clear
import ctypes
import platform


def make_dpi_aware():
    if int(platform.release()) >= 8:
        ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
make_dpi_aware()


import PySimpleGUI as sg
from time import time
import threading

def timer(timeleft_time):
    global timeleft,start
    start = time()
    seconds = timeleft_time
    while True:
        current = time()
        timeleft = int(seconds - (current - start))
        #print(timeleft)
        if event == "1" or event == "2" or event == "3" or event == "4":
            timeleft = -1
            break
        elif timeleft >= 0:
            window["t"].Update(value = timeleft)
            window.Refresh()
            if timeleft <= 0:
                sg.popup("no time left")
                window['1'].Update(disabled=True)
                window['2'].Update(disabled=True)
                window['3'].Update(disabled=True)
                window['4'].Update(disabled=True)
                window["Start"].Update(visible=True)
                window.Refresh()
            else:   
                window['1'].Update(disabled=False)
                window['2'].Update(disabled=False)
                window['3'].Update(disabled=False)
                window['4'].Update(disabled=False)
                window["Start"].Update(visible=False)
                window.Refresh()

q1 = [
        [sg.Text("Question 1!"), sg.Text("Time:"), sg.Text(" ", size=(20,1), key="t")],
        [sg.Text("This is where question 1 will be?"), sg.Button("Start")],
        [sg.Button("Option 1", key="1",button_color=("#ffffff","#151515"), disabled=True, enable_events=True), sg.Button("Option 2", key="2",button_color=("#00ff00", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Option 3", key="3",button_color=("#00ffff","#151515"), disabled=True), sg.Button("Option 4", key="4",button_color=("#ff00ff", "#151515"), disabled=True)],
        [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Next Question"), sg.Button("Skip")]
    ]

window = sg.Window("Question 1",q1)

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None:
        break
    if event == "Start":
        window['1'].Update(disabled=False)
        window['2'].Update(disabled=False)
        window['3'].Update(disabled=False)
        window['4'].Update(disabled=False)
        window["Start"].Update(visible=False)

        window.Refresh()

        seconds = 6

        timeleft = seconds
        window["t"].Update(timeleft)
        window.refresh()
        timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=timer,args = (timeleft,),daemon=True)
        timer_thread.start()

    if event == "1":
        sg.popup("Test 1")
    elif event == "2":
        sg.popup("Test 2")
    elif event == "3":
        sg.popup("Test 3")
    elif event == "4":
        sg.popup("Test 4")
```

Comment: Sorry if its too much trouble, but would you be able to run through what you have done and why breifly? Im new to pysimplegui, time and ive never come across threading before. Thanks!

Comment: In your code , code is stuck into while loop until time is over , so it get another event until loop is end which is after time complete. using thread time counter is run concurrent , so your main code is working properly. so you able to click options when timer working.

Comment: this helpful to know about threading : https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: Okay. I understand what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: After doing some research into threading I understand the code now. However, when I try to implement the code into my program, I get the error: if event == "1" or event == "2" or event == "3" or event == "4":
NameError: name 'event' is not defined . In my actual program each question is a subroutine, is this causing the error? Edit: I have found why. The function for the timer thread needs to be in each subroutine for each question. Once again, Thanks a lot!!